# Django the fastest way to do Query get list of items in row from table

Tags: python, django, web, crm

In my app I need to do fast Query but I don't know which is faster

```
materials = Material.objects.only('name')
```

Or do filter this in view

```
materials = Material.objects.all()
```

And then use for loop to show list of items from 'name' row

I think that first is better or there is better way to do this?
It cant be done with filter() because it need to show all of fields in this row.

Comment: I don't think you understand how django orm wors at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the `name`s, you can use a [**`.values_list(..)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list):

```
materials = list(Material.objects.values_list('name', flat=True))
```

This will avoid wrapping the records in `Material` objects. That being said, unless some of the columns contain (very) large amounts of data, using `.only(..)` will not significantly speed up the process. Furthermore software design-wise it is often better to fetch `Material` objects, since that means that you can define behavior in your `Material` model.

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I need. I've been reading about this in the docs about one hour ago but fatigue takes over me. Once more time, thanks man, you saved me a lot of time !